# Raspberry Pi Disk Not As Memory Card

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

my memory card used for raspberry PI is 64 GB, i check df -h it is showing less thant that. why is that such cases? In home it aready used 1.7 GB i could not find any file large as 1.7 GB

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDp5q.png)

I use rapsberry pi tool manager to perofrm the write operation

I also find out that fdisk as overall there is memory but pertiton not using that much memory,

Comment: please do not post a picture of text ... post the actual text ... format it as code, so that it displays properly

Comment: What tool did you use to write the image to the memory card? Edit your question instead of submitting a comment